# why # is not printing in dialer in the given code, I just want to print # in the dialer

Tags: java, android, xml

In this I want to print the number *555# in the dialer, but only " * * *555**" is printing not with"**#**"

[image]

Comment: Can you please share whatever code you already have so that we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're parsing a `tel:` URI here.

In a URI a hash/pound/# is a special character so you'll need to url encode it. `#` url encoded is `%23`.

So changing the string to be `"tel:*555%23"` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the # with %23

i.e.

```
"*555%23"
```